# How do you pronounce "Anti" in American english?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes, I hear it like (Antai) where the part (ai) is pronounced like the (uy) as in (Guy).

Other times, I hear it like (Anee) where the (t) sound is deleted. And the part (ee) is pronounced like the (e) as in (me).

I believe that the two pronunciations are correct because I heard them a lot so why are there two different pronunciations? Are those American and British accents? Are those two different American dialects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In California we pronounce it "an-tie." But yes it is said both ways in America although the 'anee' pronunciation is a more lazy and faster way to say it. Many people will choose that way when saying "antivirus protection/software/program."